# Storing data for applications

Tags: python, desktop-application

I have been studying programming for a few years and I am now working on my first desktop application. I am making a simple program that is able to keep track of information pertaining to a DND (Dungeons and Dragons) character/s. I want to find a way to store information about these characters so they next time the applications is launched, the characters will be saved. How do things like spotify save information about each user? First, I will give some info about the program itself. I have written it in python and it is organized as follows:

1. I have a file, which serves as the brain of the application (app.py).
2. A file which defines a class representing a character
3. A file defining a class that is used to find information about the characters
4. Other files defining classes used the build the UI

So far in my studies, I have only gathered inputted information from txt files, input functions and APIs via requests. I have worked with JSON before and am thinking this may be an option, but I am not sure how this would work in this case. I also had the idea of storing data in txt files, but want to learn the way it is done in the real world in order to make the best use of my time.

TLDR: I am making a desktop application using python and want an effective and common way people store information they want to access the next time the program is ran. I am looking for a local way to save the data that is also SAFE. If you have a recommendation that is server/cloud based, I would still like to hear how it may be done that as I am sure the knowledge will still be beneficial. I am looking for a way to SAFELY store information that will be saved even after the application is terminated. Any advice or anything you have personally used is appreciated.

Comment: You could store information locally with sqlite

Comment: As @twodayslate says, sqlite will be enough for a small app: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_python.htm